# RegEx to shorten a string

Tags: regex

I need a way to "abbreviate" a sentence. I would like to take at least 3 letters from each word, and finish abbreviating each word on a vowel or the end of that word.

For instance, if I have a string "Profit Loss Report", I would like to abbreviated it to ProfLossRep

Can somebody recommend a regex that will do this for me?

Thanks.

Comment: why did this question get downvoted? it seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Which language? This is always relevant for regex questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex appears to do the trick:

\b\w{3}[^aAeEyYuUiIoO\W$]*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex:

```
/^([a-z]{3}).*?([aeiou]|(?:.$))/i
```

The first capturing group returns the first three letters, the next returns the closest vowel or the last letter.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zUMrE/) it is in action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that with just regexp substitution. What you definitely can do is to write a small program that would do that. Here's a simple one-liner in Ruby:

```rb
p 'Profit Loss Report'.split.map { |i| i[0, 4].gsub /[aeio]*$/, '' }.join
```

Output:

```
"ProfLossRep"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for .NET:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<=          # Start at a position after...
     \b             # the start of a word 
     \p{L}{2,}      # followed by at least two letters (any letters)
     [^\P{L}aeiou]  # and one letter that isn't a vowel
    )               # End of lookbehind
    (?:             # Then match...
     [aeiou]        #  a vowel
     \p{L}*         #  plus any additional letters
    )?              # if present.
    \s*             # Match any trailing whitespace", 
    "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```